# changing width of the lg column bootstrap between 1216 and 1232

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I have created a bootstrap column using sass as follows

```
@include make-xs-column(11);
@include make-sm-column(5.8);
@include make-md-column(3.8);
@media (max-width:1232) and (min-height:1216){
    @include make-lg-column(3.8);      
}

@include make-lg-column(3.9);
```

I even tried this but now it takes width of make-lg-column(3.8)

```
@include make-xs-column(11);
            @include make-sm-column(5.8);
            @include make-md-column(3.8);
            @media (max-width:1232px) and (min-height:1216px){
                @include make-lg-column(3.8);      
            }
            @media (min-height:1217px){
            @include make-lg-column(3.9);
            }
```

I tried to change the width of lg column between 1232 and 1216 it seems not to work how do I proceed thanks in advance.